# A SF humor short story about the Navy finding a plug at the bottom of the sea, then a giant bar of soap

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, humor

Very likely to be an early Galaxy story, 1950s. Very short. The navy finds a giant iceberg that turns out to be a bar of soap, then a submarine finds a plug at the bottom of the ocean. No plot. Story ends with fearful speculation that soon it will be Saturday night and time for something to takes its bath. Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is "[Rub-A-Dub-Dub](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?84252)" (1953) by Frank Richards.  First published in *Imagination*, June 1953, it's a short two-pager.  You can read it at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Imagination_v04n05_1953-06_cape1736/page/n73/mode/2up).

The story ends:

> Sunk at the bottom of the Pacific is a bathtub stopper about three miles in circumference, and nearby floats a bar of soap about seven miles long and five wide.
> Thursday we discovered the soap, and now it's Saturday again.
>
> We're waiting.

Comment: Confirmed! Thank you. I remember the cover of that issue as one of my favorites.